Xcode iOS Simulator detects gamepad connected but nothing is actually connected
So I'm having an issue with the iOS simulator on Xcode where the code for detecting a gamepad is running, but no controller is actually connected.
Here is the code in question:
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.handleControllerDidConnect),
            name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidConnect, object: nil
        )
        
        if let controller = GCController.controllers().first {
            self.controller = controller
        }
    }


    @objc private func handleControllerDidConnect(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let gameController = notification.object as? GCController else {
            return
        }
        
        self.controller = gameController
        
        print("Controller connected")
    }

The print statement always prints out even when no controller is actually connected.
Does anyone know why the iOS simulator thinks a controller is connected? I've checked settings everywhere and can't find anything.
